# Google Maps - Same text appears in info window when using multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having an issue with multiple markers on google maps - I currently have a MySQL database storing info (location info). In php I then extract this info and loop through each postcode to dynamically create the required javascript to place a marker for each place in my database.

This works successfully so I know that I'm passing the correct information to the js function - Now what I'm trying to achieve is adding additional information when the marker is clicked but its showing the same on every marker window.

This is the js I'm using (I initiate an icon at the top but excluded this from the code for now):

```
function usePointFromPostcode(postcode, callbackFunction, text) {

    localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, 
        function() {

            if (localSearch.results[0])
            {       
                var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
                var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
                var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);
                callbackFunction(point, text);
            }else{
                alert("Postcode not found!");
            }
        }); 

    localSearch.execute(postcode + ", UK");
}

function placeMarkerAtPoint(point, html, icon)
{
    var marker = new GMarker(point,{icon: icon});

    GEvent.addListener(marker,"click",function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });

    map.addOverlay(marker);
}
```

The php code I have is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM hospitalInfo";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $code .= "usePointFromPostcode('".$row['Postcode']."', placeMarkerAtPoint, 
        '".$row['placeName']."');";

    }
}
```

$code is then echo'ed.

Any advice on why this is occuring would be much appreciated! Thanks !

Comment: Any chance that you could post a link to the page? I agree with @Cannonade that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the Google Maps code.  Are you sure that the PHP code is outputting the right stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post a link to the code since I'm hosting it on an internal server sorry. Thanks for trying to help me out. I did also think there was something wrong with the php output but I checked this by just outputting it to an alert box & it is providing different text everytime so thats why i thought there was something wrong with my javascript

Comment: This is the search I'm using:

var localSearch = new GlocalSearch();

Comment: Yes, but do you need local search?  Are you using any of the actual local search results?  Because if all you need is to get the coordinates for a post code, it might be simpler to use GClientGeocoder.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, the problem is that you're sending several requests before you get any results, and the value of the marker text changes each time you send the request.  I think you could greatly simplify your code by using the GClientGeocoder - unless it's absolutely necessary to use GLocalSearch, which isn't really part of the Maps API.  Here's [Google's tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Object) for the geocoder.

First create the geocoder like this:

```
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
```

Next, here's your new **usePointFromPostcode()** function:

```
function usePointFromPostcode(postcode, text) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(postcode, function(point) {
        if (!point) {
            //alert('address not found');
        } else {
            var marker = new GMarker(point, {icon: icon});
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(text);
            });
            map.addOverlay(marker);
        }
    });
}
```

This worked great for me.  Try it out and let us know how it goes.

If you need more information about the returned point, like accuracy, use [getLocations()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GClientGeocoder.getLocations) instead of getLatLng().  The tutorial explains how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You may be having a scope/closure problem, similar to the issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078309/google-maps-api-all-markers-opening-the-same-infowindow).

Try replacing this code:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker,"click",function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
});
```

with this:

```
marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(html);
```

If that doesn't work, I'd guess that the closure problem is coming from the setSearchCompleteCallback() function.  It's difficult to guess without seeing the actual page.

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error - I've managed to find a temporary hack that seemed to work for now - I just added a pause in the php code with setTimeout. I think the issue is because the method usePointFromPostcode gets called again before the search results from the previous has been returned - searching must be asynchronous? Didn't know how to fix in code so used the timeout instead. Any other thoughts? 
Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: You're completely right. usePointFromPostcode() gets called multiple times before the first result gets back.  I'm going to post a new answer...

Comment: marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(html); has made my day!  Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with your Google Maps Code.  I suggest you try logging the html parameters in placeMarkerAtPoint and the text param to the localSearch callback.  Google have a very useful logging API you could use:

GLog Reference

I would add at the begining of the placeMarkerAtPoint function:

```
GLog.write ("placeMarkerAtPoint - " + html);
```

and in the localSearch callback:

```
GLog.write ("SearchCompleteCallback - " + text);
```

I think the logging for these two callbacks (particularly the second one), will make it obvious where the html is getting lost.

Update: Ok, based on your logging your PHP code is fine.  You are generating three calls to usePointFromPostcode.

The problem here is with your google.search.SearchControl callback.  I am assuming the search is working correctly and the results array you get back is appropriate for each respective postcode?

If so, then the problem is with the text parameter in the setSearchCompleteCallback.  I haven't used the [Google AJAX Search](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html) stuff, but the problem lies in how these callbacks are fired.  It looks like you can get [multiple callbacks](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GSearchControl) for a single execute.

Comment: I tried this - still no luck on what is going wrong... I've posted a reply with results and javascript code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're re-using the name marker so the last text you place ends up getting attached to all of them. Create an index and name them marker1, marker2, etc. Its easy to do in a php loop.